# Grails image url loads but image doesn't load?

Tags: image, model-view-controller, grails

In grails, images url loads fine but image doesn't display...

```
def thumbphoto = {
    response.setContentType('image/jpeg')
    response.setHeader('Cache-control', 'no-cache')

    if(params.id){
      userId = params.id
    }
    if(params?.id != null && !(params?.id.empty)){ 

      params.maxWidth?: 50.00
      params.maxHeight?: 50.00
      response.outputStream << imageProxyService.loadThumbnailImage(params.id, securityService.passwordEncoder(userId.toString()))
    }
  }
```

User has many images 
This is the gsp view where i am trying to load and display images along with status updates.

```
<g:each in="${statusList}" status="i" var="status" status="i">
            <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}">
            <tr>
              <td>
            <g:if test="${status.photo != null  && !(status.photo.empty)}" >
                  <img id="profile_photo" src="${createLink(controller:'image', action:'thumbphoto', id:status.photo, params:[maxWidth:50.0,maxHeight:50.0,id:status.id])}" alt="" title="" />

            </g:if>
            <g:else>
              <img id="profile_photo" src="${resource(dir:'images', file:'no_image_blue.gif')}" alt="No Image" width="50" height="50"/>
            </g:else>
            </td>
            <td>${status.id}: ${status.message}</td>
            </tr>
            </tr>
          </g:each>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/), and go to the **Net** tab.

You should see all the HTTP requests and their statuses.

You're likely get a *404* for your image, check its location under your *webapps* folder...

Again Firebug will give you all the hints and solutions.

Comment: @rimero- is my controller troubling images display?

Comment: Its an internal server error after oberving with firebug.
@rimero - Is my controller or image service is set up the way so it only loads and works with session images?
Please help... :(

Comment: Please post the relevant stack trace from the grails logs. Could it be related to Spring security and no current user? The error message will help

Comment: Thanks for your help... I figured it out.. I used dynamic finders to get user id and passed it on to image controller to render images... Worked... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [g:img](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Tags/img.html).

```
<g:img dir="/image/showImage/9921355add3b115766ad41effdf000db9e461570.jpg" alt=""/>
```

Comment: I am using this in my gsp actually...
<img id="profile_photo" src="${createLink(controller:'image', action:'thumbphoto', id:status.photo)}" alt="" title="" />

Comment: I am using grails 1.3.7
and need to load images dynamically from image controller...

Comment: I have updated the main question with image controller and gsp - @user2264997

Comment: access your img url directly - this should render where the error is comming from. Also keep eye on logs in console - there will also be some info. If logs aren't verbose enough, decrease log level to info or debug.

Comment: how do i access it directly? little more info please... @jjczopek

Comment: In browser enter address which points directly to you controller action with all required params. You should get error if there is something wrong in controller.

Comment: Yes I have already tried that and link and action is right its just image is not displaying... my profile photo use the same function and everything and it is displaying image all right. @jjczopek

Comment: After hours of research and attempts, I found out that: all the images url load all right but wont get displayed. the only images displayed are of the session user and i want to load images related to all the users... @jjczopek